# foursquare venues/suggestcompletion doesn`t support math any part of word

Tags: search, foursquare

I'm trying to send following request:

```
venues/suggestCompletion?ll=54.850945,83.100677&query=wear
```

**Response**:

```
 id: "4e620509b993678bb634372c"
 name: "Wearewowagency"
 location: {
    ...
 }
```

I'm trying to send following request:

```
venues/suggestCompletion?ll=54.850945,83.100677&query=wow
```

**Response**:

```
{
    meta: {
        code: 200
    }
    notifications: [
        {
            type: "notificationTray"
            item: {
                unreadCount: 0
            }
        }
    ]
    response: {
        minivenues: [ ]
    }
}
```

**Output**:
LIKE str% doesn`t support LIKE %str%.

Comment: No question, bug report. I was looking to write, I only found stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because there are not any interesting venues to return. If you are looking for venues that starts with "ins", then you get a response.

> https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/suggestCompletion%3Fll%3D54.850945,83.100677%26query%3Dins

Remember that not all venues are returned from the venues/suggestCompletion endpoint.

Comment: No you are wrong, they simply have not searched about the word, just looked up from the beginning,
your example:
[link](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/suggestCompletion%3Fll%3D54.850945,83.100677%26query%3Dins)

first result: "Institute of Computational Technologies"
new query "logies":
[link](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/suggestCompletion%3Fll%3D54.850945,83.100677%26query%3Dlogies)
no result.